# How to solve the java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.integrator.internal.IntegratorServiceImpl

Tags: java, hibernate, nosuchmethoderror

I am new to hibernate and I was trying to build a JSF application with Hibernate in the persistence layer. This is how I am getting the Session Factory.

```
Configuration config = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
        StandardServiceRegistryBuilder ssrb = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(config.getProperties());
        factory = config.buildSessionFactory(ssrb.build());
```

But I am getting the following error while running the application.

```
Error Message:
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.integrator.internal.IntegratorServiceImpl.<init>(Ljava/util/LinkedHashSet;Lorg/hibernate/boot/registry/classloading/spi/ClassLoaderService;)V
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder.build(BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder.java:247)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.<init>(StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.java:73)
    at com.sherwin.j29.jpa.factory.JPASessionFactory.createSessionFactory(JPASessionFactory.java:19)
    at com.sherwin.j29.jpa.factory.JPASessionFactory.getSessionFactory(JPASessionFactory.java:13)
    at com.sherwin.j29.dao.WorkItemDAO.<init>(WorkItemDAO.java:24)
    at com.sherwin.j29.dao.WorkItemDAO$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.<init>(WorkItemDAO$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections$16.work(SecureReflections.java:344)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.run(SecureReflectionAccess.java:52)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.runAsInstantiation(SecureReflectionAccess.java:173)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections.newInstance(SecureReflections.java:341)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyFactory.create(ProxyFactory.java:237)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ClientProxyFactory.create(ClientProxyFactory.java:105)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ClientProxyProvider.createClientProxy(ClientProxyProvider.java:87)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ClientProxyProvider.access$000(ClientProxyProvider.java:43)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ClientProxyProvider$1.load(ClientProxyProvider.java:53)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ClientProxyProvider$1.load(ClientProxyProvider.java:46)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3589)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2374)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2337)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2252)
```

I am using hibernate 4.3.6.

Please let me know if I am missing something.

Comment: Please check more than one hibernate jar may be present in your lib

Comment: I have included the hibernate 4.3.6 final jar .. but when my jboss starts up it shows the following line.                  08:39:31,473 INFO  [org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.1.Final-redhat-2}
08:39:31,491 INFO  [org.hibernate.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.2.14.SP1-redhat-1}
08:39:31,494 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found

Comment: Not sure from where it is picking up the hibernate core 4.2.14 SP1

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have removed all of the previous version(s) of Hibernate from your classpath.

Looking at it on github, I do not see why that would be caused unless you were having class loader issues caused by version conflicts, as the IntegratorServiceImpl exists in both versions that you are/were using, which suggests a class loader issue to me

Answer (score 0):

Try to **clean and build** your project if you had any package upgrade recently.